# Can you help me with my for loop? it isn't turning the right amount of degrees

Tags: java

```
public void turnLeft(double degrees) {
    for (int i = 0; i < degrees; i++) {
        this.left(degrees);
    }
}
```

This code helps my turtle turn how many ever degrees I want it to, but when I put in like 180 degrees it only turns 90.

Comment: What does the implementation for `left` look like, and why does it need to be called with the same argument `degrees` number of times?

Comment: Do you really need that for loop?

Comment: First, your loop is not needed. It seems like you are calling 'left' method the same amount as your 'degree'. Secondly, I am really not sure about your code. However if you are sure that it is correct and it turns `90` instead of `180`. Just `degrees = degrees * 2;` before the loop as a workaround!

Comment: How are you implementing this? Are you using Math.cos/sin which use radians, not degrees?

Comment: how "left" function looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that your implementation of the `left` method rotates turtle on degrees number, specified with method parameter.

In your case (calling of the `turnLeft(180)`) the loop will do the following:

`this.left(1);
this.left(2);
...
this.left(180);`

so... it very similar with calling the `turnLeft` method with number of degrees equals `1+2+3+...+180` it is  `16110`

So in this case your turtle makes `16110 div 360 = 44` whole cycles and then rotate on `16110 mod 360 = 270` degrees. So it will be in `90` degrees from your initial state.
But it is only my guess what could be happen.

Comment: That's what I thought originally (and wrote in my now deleted answer), but the OP calls `this.left(degrees)` inside the loop, not `this.left(i)`.

Comment: You are right. I had messed this. Looks like it is impossible to explain the actual result without exploring an implementation of the `left` method